# Is there a paradox that doesn't require self-reference and negation?

Tags: logic, paradoxes

Is there a paradox that doesn't require self-reference and negation?

`The set of all sets that do not contain themselves` uses both, for example. Same with `This sentence is false`.

Comment: Depends on your definition of paradox. 
The [Banach-Tarski paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Tarski_paradox) may be a candidate for your requirements.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, wrong copypaste of link: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/475849/paradoxes-without-self-reference.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla: Okay, I'll buy that -- hereby dupehammered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Yablo paradox](http://www.mit.edu/~yablo/pwsr.pdf) is an example